# Trying to execute sql query in method and view it on the .net view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to execute an sql query from a class.

I did this by creating this method:

```
public class GetSQL
{
    public static string getsomedata(string data)
    {
        database2Entities db2 = new database2Entities();
     
        var output = db2.cards.SqlQuery("SELECT cardName from cards WHERE cardID ="+ data);
        
        var outputtostring = output.ToString();
        return outputtostring;
    }
 
}
```

I have then called it from the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<StockManagementSystem.Models.form>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Full_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cardtype)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Full_Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cardtypeid)
           
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @{
                    StockManagementSystem.Models.database2Entities db = new StockManagementSystem.Models.database2Entities();
                    List<StockManagementSystem.Models.card> ListCategory = db.cards.ToList();
                    var outputdata = @item.cardtypeid.ToString();
                    var result = StockManagementSystem.App_Code.GetSQL.getsomedata(outputdata);

                                <label>@result</label>

    
                }
                @*@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cardtypeid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
            </div>
            
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.FormID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.FormID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.FormID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

but my output is always this: "SELECT cardName from card WHERE cardID =" (plus the data that is passed)

I have tried changing the sql query, and I have also tried this query on mysql, which works. The problem is the output. All other details in the index.cshtml are generated, the only thing that isn't is this query.

Comment: What is the return type of `db2.cards.SqlQuery` ?

Comment: I converted ToString(); @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: That means SqlQuery method returns `"SELECT cardName from card WHERE cardID ="` ? And when you do `ToString()` it just returns `"SELECT cardName from card WHERE cardID ="`... ? Can you also explain what output do you expect, in the question?

Comment: Ok yeah, that does make a lot of sense, but I have come across a question and  the person started using for example db.cards.SQLQuery<string>(), but mine returns an error stating that DBset<cards> cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: try `db2.cards.SqlQuery<StockManagementSystem.Models.card>`

Comment: It returns the same error -             string output = db2.cards.SqlQuery<card>("SELECT cardName from cards WHERE cardID =" + data); I have also tried changing the output variable to string instead of var

Comment: That's where I need to know the return type of `db2.cards.SqlQuery` method. You can see the return type of the method by right click the method -> click Go to Definition. It should show the method signature. The first part of the signature after `public` keyword is the return type. Can you share it?Can you share the exact error message you are receiving?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It is string for the method getsomedata, and  public virtual DbSqlQuery<TEntity> SqlQuery(string sql, params object[] parameters); for the db2.cards.sqlquery

Comment: as for the error it's - Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0308 The non-generic method 'DbSet<card>.SqlQuery(string, params object[])' cannot be used with type arguments 3_App_Code C:\Users\user1\source\repos\StockManagementSystem\StockManagementSystem\App_Code\GetSQL.cs 15 Active

Comment: Looks like DbSet.SqlQuery is not a generic method. That's why you can not use `<Card>` or any other type there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0. You might want to try `db2.cards.SqlQuery("SELECT cardName from cards WHERE cardID ="+ data).ToList<StockManagementSystem.Models.card>()`